How to use IHttpClientFactory to upload a file to a FTP Server
I have a method, where I use the deprecated WebClient class to upload a file to a FTP Server.
public async Task<BaseResponse<Void>> Handle(FTPUploadRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    using WebClient client = new()
    {
        Credentials = new NetworkCredential(configuration.FTP.User, configuration.FTP.Password.Decrypt())
    };

   static string BuildUri(FTPUploadRequest request, IOptionsSnapshot<Configuration> configuration) 
       => $"ftp://{configuration.FTP.Server}/{request.DirectoryPath}/{request.FileName}";

   client.UploadFile(
       BuildUri(request, configuration),
       WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile,
       request.FilePath + "/" + request.FileName);

   return await BaseResponse<Void>.Create(true);
}

WebClient is obsolete and not Unit-testable. The message is:
SYSLIB0014 'WebClient.WebClient()' is obsolete: 'WebRequest, HttpWebRequest, ServicePoint, and WebClient are obsolete. Use HttpClient instead.'

So I wanted to inject IHttpClientFactory which is also stated in the obsolete message. I can easily do that, but how should I upload the file? Posting against a FTP Server with a multi-part-message?
I have no idea and cannot find any solution on the internet.
Any Ideas?

FTP isn't HTTP. FTP is connection oriented, HTTP is statless. There's no "basic authentication" in FTP. You can't use HttpClient, much less HttpClientFactory, to work with FTP. FTP requests work against the current folder, while HTTP has no folders. WebClient and FtpWebRequest tried to cover up the difference (eg by creating a new connection to the same server for every request) but things always broke down after a point. For example, there's no standard format for a directory listing and FtpWebRequest only supports a few variants

NuGet has several FTP packages. One of the most popular and actively maintained is FluentFTP with 29M downloads, with the latest version released last month. The server support section shows it supports the extensions (and quirks) of a lot of FTP servers.

@PanagiotisKanavos Ok, but why is the message stating to use HttpClient instead? What is the prefered way of uploading files to a FTP Server only with build in .NET methods?

Because you tried to use WebClient. The compiler doesn't know that you intend to pass an FTP URI at runtime. There are no built-in .NET methods for FTP, or, more importantly, for SFTP. The preferred method is to use a good library like FluentFTP.

"What is the prefered way of uploading files to a FTP Server only with build in .NET methods?" - There aren't any. The default use case for WebClient was Http. That part has been replaced by HttpClient. But there isn't a complementary FtpClient that I am aware of. But opting for a well-known and widely used NuGet isn't that much of a deal and still much better than using deprecated API. So, in short, I would consider that to be "the preferred way".

I will give it a try with FluentFTP. Thx guys. .

You don't.
HTTP and FTP are completely different protocols.
You want to use an FTP Client.
FluentFTP seems like a good bet.
